# Is there way to set the current location to something other than the center in UIMap?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview

I want to show my current location on the left-hand side of the map.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
theCoordinate.latitude = 26.926;
theCoordinate.longitude = 75.8235;
MKCoordinateRegion region;
region.center = theCoordinate;
MKCoordinateSpan span;
span.latitudeDelta = 0.005;
span.longitudeDelta = 0.005;
region.span=span;
[mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
```

The above code shows my location in the center of the map because of this line:

```
region.center = theCoordinate;
```

Is there a way to change this on any specific position other than the center?

Thank you.

Nitesh

Comment: What do you want to achieve by this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not specific to Objective-C. You need to calculate what the center would be, if the desired location is on the left of the map. ie, given a map of width X in pixels, and scale T, what is the long/lat of the point X/2 pixels east of my position. Once you have that, you can assign

```
region.center = theNewCoordinate;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a kind of offset ?

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinatesForCenter = [theCoordinate copy];

// Add an offset :
coordinatesForCenter.latitude+=5;    // 5 for exemple (it's not significant)
coordinatesForCenter.longitude+=5;

// Center on your new coordinates :
region.center = coordinatesForCenter;
```

Hope it helps.